# C : How to detect if execvp waiting for standard input?

Tags: c, pipe, fork, exec, stdin

I've made a daemon that launch commands.

If the execvp function waiting for standard input (with cat, grep, wc, by example), I have to redirect stdin to a named pipe.

Currently, my daemon always open the named pipe and redirect stdin before execvp, 
I have to manually CTRL+D so that the execution of commands can continue.

**I would like to use this pipe only if the command asking for standard input.**

Example:

**cat | wc -l** : I'm opening my named pipe and redirect stdin to it before execvp

**ls | wc -l** : I don't open the named pipe, execvp pass successfully

Here is how I want my program to work:
[image]

[image]

Comment: So you want to predict in advance whether the command is going to read standard input or not?

Comment: Exactly. Or any trick that would permit me to open the pipe (and redirect stdin to it) only if command is going to read standard input.

Comment: You could ptrace() the forked process to detect when it reads standard input, but by then it's too late to switch it to read from a pipe instead.

Comment: I've added details on my post, do you think there is a cleaner/easier solution ?

Comment: Does the client tell the daemon which named pipe (if any) to use for standard input? If no pipe is specified, the daemon could open /dev/null and use that as standard input for the command.

Comment: Yes, the client send a struct as request which contains the command and the two named pipes.

Comment: And can the client tell the daemon _not_ to use a named pipe for a particular command? If not, surely it is the client's responsibility to close the pipe that supplies standard input to the command.

Comment: Currently no it doesn't. It's exactly what I search, but how I can check that the command will read standard input ? I thinked to make a condition that pipe will not be used if the command is grep, cat or wc, but isn't very modular, I don't know how much shell commands are going to read standard input.

Comment: The only way I can see it working is if the client opens its "read" pipe (pipe2 in the picture) in non-blocking mode (and then possibly sets it back to blocking mode after opening) before it sends the request to the daemon and then opens its "write" (pipe1) pipe in normal, blocking mode. Likewise, the daemon opens its "read" pipe (pipe1 in the picture) in non-blocking mode (and then sets it back to blocking mode before running the command) and its "write" pipe (pipe2) in blocking mode. The opens of the "write" pipes will not block if the other end of the same pipe is already open.

Comment: It's working, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can see it working is if the client opens its "read" pipe (pipe2 in the picture) in non-blocking mode (and then possibly sets it back to blocking mode after opening) before it sends the request to the daemon and then opens its "write" (pipe1) pipe in normal, blocking mode. Likewise, the daemon opens its "read" pipe (pipe1 in the picture) in non-blocking mode (and then sets it back to blocking mode before running the command) and its "write" pipe (pipe2) in blocking mode. The opens of the "write" pipes will not block if the other end of the same pipe is already open. – Ian Abbott